# Currency and decimal editor in Ultragrid

Tags: vb.net, formatting, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have to format some of the `datatypes` for cell values of an `ultragrid`. I have used the `DateTimeEditor` for formatting the `datetime` values.

//Code

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeRow(object sender, InitializeRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.ReInitialize == false)
   {
       DefaultEditorOwnerSettings editorSettings;
       DateTimeEditor datetime_editor;
       string condition = e.Row.GetCellValue("Condition").ToString();
       switch (condition)
       {
            case "TEST1":
                editorSettings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings()
                editorSettings.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
                editorSettings.MaskInput = "mm/dd/yyyy";
                datetime_editor = new DateTimeEditor(new DefaultEditorOwner(editorSettings));
                e.Row.Cells["DateInfo"].Editor = datetime_editor;
                break;
            case "TEST2":
                editorSettings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings()
                editorSettings.DataType = typeof(DateTime);
                editorSettings.MaskInput = "hh:mm:ss";
                datetime_editor = new DateTimeEditor(new DefaultEditorOwner(editorSettings));
                e.Row.Cells["DateInfo"].Editor = datetime_editor;
                break;
       }
   }
}
```

Now, How can I format the `currency` and `decimal` values?

Is there any `currencyeditor` or `decimaleditor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a EditorWithMask, but keep in mind that a column has a datatype and if your column datatype is not compatible with the expected Editor datatype  the results are unpredictable

```
EditorWithMask currency_editor;
DefaultEditorOwnerSettings editorSettings = new DefaultEditorOwnerSettings();
editorSettings.DataType = typeof(decimal);
currency_editor = new EditorWithMask(new DefaultEditorOwner(editorSettings));
editorSettings.MaskInput = "€ nnn.nn";
e.Row.Cells["decimal_column_name"].Editor = mask_editor;
```

Comment: The same declared and initialized in the other tests, ok, I will add it to the answer

Comment: No, when I try to use this code in my application it says "not declared". What to do?

Comment: I am supposing that this code is used in the context of your question when the editorsettings variable is declared above the switch statement. It this is not the case then declare it yourself. You have the code.

Comment: How can I help you? You see the code where you use the variable. You should declare it and only then you could use the variable. If the compiler refuses to accept the code it is because the variable is not declared or its declaration is not visible in the point where you use it, simply as that. Update the question with your real code

Comment: Kindly help on this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312414/standard-formatting-vs-custom-formatting-in-ultragridcells

Comment: You can format the column by setting the Style = 'Currency' and Format = 'c'. This works for me for displaying a decimal value in the currency column.

Answer (score -3):

Try this coding
currencyColumn.Format = "##,###,####.00"

Thanks